# print number of digits of an integer

Tags: c

How to print just for example 3 last digits of a signed integer as hexadecimal number?

`int num = -5;`

`printf("%03X\n", num);`

prints `FFFFFFFB`

I need it to print just `FFB`

Comment: `num & ~(0xFFFFFFFF<<12);`

Comment: The first problem is that you cannot print a signed integer as a hexadecimal number, only unsigned integers... that printed as signed hexadecimal would be -5...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best and clearest way to do this would be a bitmask to hide everything except the last few digits. In your case, this would be `printf("%X\n", num & 0xfff);`:

```
0xfffffffb
0x00000fff
  -----|||
0x00000ffb
```

You can adapt this to work with higher bits too. So if you want to extract `0xadb` from `0xdeadbeef`, it would look like this:

```
(0xdeadbeef & 0xfff000) >> 12 // gives 0xadb
```

`(0xdeadbeef & 0xfff000)` will mask out the bits you want, leaving `0xadb000`. To remove these zeroes, right shift by 12 (each hex digit can represent 4 bits, and we need to remove 3 digits, so 4*3 = 12).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
void printLastThreeHex(int num)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    char tmp[sizeof(int)*2 + 1]; // two hex chars for each byte + null char
    char* str = tmp;

    sprintf(tmp, "%03x", num);
    len = strlen(tmp);
    if (len > 3)
    {
        str = tmp + len - 3;
    }

    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```